# Merge tag:postgresql-performance with tag:query-performance?

Tags: discussion, tagging, retag-request

The [postgresql-performance](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/postgresql-performance) is well looked after by an excellent Postgres contributor, but it's just a special case of [query-performance](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/query-performance) applied to a specific RDBMS.

I feel that it should be merged, and the information in the Tag Wiki moved to [query-performance](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/query-performance) or other postgres tags as appropriate:

> [image]

> [image]

Comment: I'm trying to start a discussion, not push for my solution. Perhaps there is a great reason for the tag I haven't thought of, and if so, hopefully that will be spelled out in an answer here, so if anyone else asks we have somewhere to point them.

Answer (score 6):

Given that every single question that is tagged [postgres-performance](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/postgres-performance) will also be tagged [postgres](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/postgres), the only gain in having a separate [postgres-performance](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/postgres-performance) tag is the ability to have a customized tag wiki.

The tag wiki itself is great, and especially in this middle paragraph, there is significant Postgres-specific advice:

> Consider the basic advice on [Performance Optimization](https://wiki.postgresql.org/wiki/Performance_Optimization) and [Slow Query Questions](https://wiki.postgresql.org/wiki/Slow_Query_Questions) in PostgreSQL Wiki before asking questions on this tag, including the "Things to try before you post" section. [`Using EXPLAIN`](https://wiki.postgresql.org/wiki/Using_EXPLAIN) is particularly important. Useful [ebooks](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/books/) are freely available.

The down-side is that it invites fragmentation of *all* other tags — do we really want to go down the line of having [postgres-database-design](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/postgres-database-design), [postgres-replication](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/postgres-replication) etc? The benefit would be the same for these cases too, namely that we could create tag wikis with Postgres-specific links and information.

Alternatively, why not just have a single 'performance' tag, and divide the tag wiki into sections for each RDBMS? All the text in the [postgres-performance](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/postgres-performance) tag wiki could be transferred 'as is' into [query-performance](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/query-performance) et al.

There are two bits of data we are lacking that might be helpful to have from Stack Exchange:

1. How often is the tag wiki page visited.
2. Which tagging system is more beneficial for search purposes.

Comment: Gawd, I hate to disagree with @Erwin ever, but you win this one. I'm also very active on [tag:postgresql]. It makes *far* more sense to me not to go down the path of having RDBMS-specific subtags for everything. And, it's not like you can't query for it.. [postgresql]+[query-performance] is simply better. Somethings should just chance and should have never been.

Comment: Well, both of you have a point, the systematics is cleaner with separate tags, but there are drawbacks. If we cram instructions and information for 10 different RDBMS in a single tag, who will read it? People hate reading long text. I can't think of a better place to maintain that kind of information than a tag wiki. Currently, quite a few people actually read it and follow at least some instructions. Maybe a meta question with a canonical community wiki answer? Edits on tag wikis are conveniently reserved for users with reputation in the tag ...

Comment: @Erwin My feeling is that Meta is the way to go — perhaps a compressed version in the tag Wiki with links to meta for each RDBMS. In practice I doubt there will be 10 sections — more like 3 or 4 at most.

Answer (score 5):

### No action needed

#### Benefits of the *status quo*

- The [postgresql-performance](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/postgresql-performance) tag is relatively popular (253 questions)
- It is actively curated and promoted by its subject area experts both here and on SO
- The tag Excerpt and Wiki are (unusually!) useful, appropriate, and targeted to the intended usage

This tag therefore **adds value** to the community *in the practical way it is used*.

#### Merge drawbacks

Someone will need to review the result to:

- Ensure the new tag is actually appropriate in each case
- Add [postgres](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/postgres) to the question if needed
- Remove references (perhaps in comments) to the removed tag

We will also need to **notify** people with the old tag in their **subscriptions** and **filters** to change these to [postgres](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/postgres) plus [query-performance](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/query-performance) (where that is even possible).

This **makes work** for the subject area experts, without providing them with any compensating benefit.

It will also deprive them of a tool **they explicitly created** and actively use & maintain.

#### Conclusion

Why bother with this change?

The current tag appears useful to the people using it, and is not causing any **actual harm** to the site.

Making the change may **inconvenience** existing tag users, and require moderator time to implement.

The only benefit seems to be to eliminate a perceived technical redundancy in the tagging system.

It does not set a precedent. New tags are reviewed on their merits.

Comment: Merge drawbacks is a tactical question that has no place on whether or not the merge should happen. The rest is an argument from the status-quo which seems very weak. We should prefer the status-quo pass some intellectual rigor rather than accepting it. @Jack presented an argument *for* a change. And, as far as I can see your argument boils down to the change being difficult, and it being a change of some sort. Presumably, Jack will address your merge concerns and do it properly. If so, could you argue that we would be worse off a week after the change, or not?

Comment: I added this option so people had something else to vote on.

Answer (score 4):

I think discussing / tuning / optimizing performance is sufficiently distinct for the various RDBMS to warrant a separate tag. We have put some thought into refining information, instructions and resources in [postgresql-performance](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/postgresql-performance) and it serves well so far. (I say "we" because it started with [the related tag on SO](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/postgresql-performance/info).)

If general performance aspects are involved, it can make sense to additionally or instead tag one or more of [performance](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/performance), [query-performance](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/query-performance), [performance-tuning](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/performance-tuning) - which also serve well for RDBMS that don't have a specific [this-rdbms-performance](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/this-rdbms-performance) (yet).

Other than that, I can subscribe to what [Paul answered](https://dba.meta.stackexchange.com/a/2705/3684). The tag should stay.